# Make visual studio understand angularjs in a new file

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

This is probably a silly question but i am having troubles programming in angularjs with visual studio whenever i separate the application to different files.

For example, if i include everything in the same file (index.html):

```
<script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Visual studio automatically understands what is the object angular and what functions in contains and whenevery i type "angular.", it opens a window with suggestions.

But when i separate everything to different files, for example: app.js, routing.js, controllers.js, etc...

The application still runs but since i include angularjs in one file and use it in a different file, visual studio doesn't "help" me anymore...

So yeah.. it's silly but it really helps me program, especially because i'm new to angularjs.

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: it gives you the intellisense for angularjs if you use it in the one file? is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NuGet**

If you would like to add AngularJS intellisence to your project you should add the NuGet package by John Bledsoe. There is a full article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/02/05/using-angularjs-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) it explains how to add the package so you have the coding help you require.

**File Structure**

There is a great article [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) that shows you the best way to structure your AngularJS application. Its a great article and can help when handling larger AngularJS projects but should be used even for smaller apps.